# Why doesn't this Blazor WebAssembly api Get function work?

Tags: api, routes, blazor, webassembly, blazor-webassembly

[image]I have a Blazor WASM app and am just modifying the template weatherforecastcontroller to add a Get where I can pass in an id:

```
        [HttpGet("{userId}")]

        public string Get(string userId)
        {
            return userId;
        }
```

and on component that calls it:

```
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {   
            var id = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<WeatherForecast>("WeatherForecast/1);        
    }
```

but an error is thrown:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
      Unhandled exception rendering component: The provided ContentType is not supported; the supported types are 'application/json' and the structured syntax suffix 'application/+json'.
System.NotSupportedException: The provided ContentType is not supported; the supported types are 'application/json' and the structured syntax suffix 'application/+json'.
  at System.Net.Http.Json.HttpContentJsonExtensions.ValidateContent (System.Net.Http.HttpContent content) <0x2f6ff90 + 0x0009a> in <filename unknown>:0
```

so what is wrong? If I manually type into address bar :

http://localhost:59728/weatherforecast/1

...I get the id like I expect.

Comment: The obvious error is trying to deserialize a simple `string` as an entire `WeatherForecast` object. What does your service return though? Do you get an error page instead of a reply perhaps? Check the `Network` tab in your browser's Developer tools. What is the response to your request?

Comment: I changed the return type to string, see comments below. Network tab shows an item called 1 (if I pass that as the userId), of type fetch and status of 200. When I click it, it says 'failed to load response data. No data found for resource with given identifier'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

`Http.GetFromJsonAsync<WeatherForecast>`

Should be
`Http.GetFromJsonAsync<string>`

In other words, the type specifier, which instruct the json serializer as to what type to expect from the HTTP call is string, and not the name of a class, `WeatherForecast`

Update:

```
@page "/"
@inject HttpClient Http


<h1>@output</h1>

@code
{
    private string output;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        var val = "1";
        output = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<string>($"WeatherForecast?value={val}");

    }
}
```

### WeatherForecastController.cs

```
[HttpGet]
        public string Get(string value)
        {

            return value;
        }
```

### Startup.ConfigureServices method

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
            {
               options.OutputFormatters.RemoveType<StringOutputFormatter>();
            });
            services.AddRazorPages();
        }
```

Note: You can also add the `Produces` attribute to specify the response type format, like this:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Produces("application/json")]
    public string Get(string value)
    {

        return value;
    }
```

You should also change

```
services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
                {
                   options.OutputFormatters.RemoveType<StringOutputFormatter>();
                });
```

To

```
services.AddControllersWithViews();
```

Comment: I changed the call line to 'var id = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<string>("WeatherForecast/1");' and I still get the same error

Comment: @E.D. Sorry, I've updated my answer. It should work...

Comment: @enet - i think it's an issue w/ Content-Type, no?  (plus your GetFromJsonAsync<> fix)

Comment: It's rather the how you specify the response format. I've added a better solution.

Comment: Ok changing return to 'ActionResult<string>' and returning 'return new JsonResult(returnValue.ToString());' worked. Not sure who should get the correct answer. Thx all for the help

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the fix suggested by @enet, there is also an issue with your controller.  When you return a `string`, the `Content-Type` is being set to `text/plain` and your HTTP client is expecting JSON.  Here is an example:

```
    [HttpGet("text")]
    public string GetText()
    {
        return "Hello, this is text/plain";
    }


    [HttpGet("maybe-json")]
    public ActionResult<string> GetMaybeJson()
    {
        return Ok("Hello, this is still text/plain.");
    }

    // ** THIS SHOULD WORK ** 
    [HttpGet("json")]
    public ActionResult<string> GetJson()
    {
        return new JsonResult("Hello, this is application/json");
    }
```

[image]

Similarly, if you had tested with the endpoints returning `WeatherForecast`, then the `Content-Type` would've been `application/json` and your Blazor code would work.  You should be able to try `GetJson()` in your controller and see your code work.

Comment: This answer (the 'return new JsonResult("Hello, this is application/json" part) is probably the best. It's the most common way of doing it and the most easily read by other devs.
 The other answers are interesting and I learned some things, but not very common.

Answer (score 1):

You say when you call the API directly, it works, but is it returning `1` or `"1"`?  This is important as only the latter is valid JSON.  Since you're asking for JSON (`GetFromJsonAsync`), then the raw value `1` will cause a problem.  As [the docs state](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/formatting?view=aspnetcore-6.0):

> By default, string return types are formatted as text/plain

You can review the docs to see about potential solutions.  Here's a snippet:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllers(options =>
{
    // Removes the special case for strings
    options.OutputFormatters.RemoveType<StringOutputFormatter>();
});
```

Other options include manually returning an `HttpResponseMessage` with the string value specified in an instance of `StringContent`.

Note: enet is also right that you need to change `WeatherForecast` to `string`.

Comment: the string returned is valid JSON. I made sure by using an online validator. It's in proper quotes

Comment: Then did you manually override the default behavior of returning it without quotes?

Comment: not sure what you mean. If I change the line to : return "1"; I still get the error

Comment: That's not what I mean at all.  What does it show in the browser when you go to your API's URL?  Please show a screenshot of your developer tools' network tab as it's clearly not returning a response with a content type of `application/json`.

Comment: I started a new template WASM project from scratch and the error gives slight different info: Unhandled exception rendering component: The JSON value could not be converted to System.String. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 1.
System.Text.Json.JsonException: The JSON value could not be converted to System.String. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 1.
 ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot get the value of a token type 'Number' as a string.
   at System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader.GetString()
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.StringConverter.Read

Comment: screenshot of network tab added to OP

Comment: I did notice if I leave the return type as WeatherForecast and actually return a WeatherForecast object it works. Do I have to return an object of type related to the controller? Or one of it's properties? i.e. WeatherForecast.Summary or whatever